# Масштабирование фона css js

Tags: javascript, css

[Здесь](http://cloud.geranya.in.ua/Boxify/), когда задаю background-image через класс в css и также свойство `background-size: cover`, то фон при масштабировании растягивается на всю ширину (что мне и нужно), но сейчас я задаю несколько фонов (сменяющихся после обновления страницы) через js, в итоге, свойство `background-size: cover` не срабатывает, и фон просто центрируется.

Добавляла в js `back-size:cover`, но не работает.

js:

```
$(document).ready(function() { 
  var randomBg = 'url(img/bg' + Math.ceil(Math.random() * 3) + '.jpg)'; 
  var repeatBg = 'no-repeat center center'; 
  var sizeBg = 'cover';
  $('body').css('background', randomBg + repeatBg); 
});
```

В каком направлении копать?

Comment: покажите свой код для того чтобы мы могли найти ошибку ...

Comment: Вот js: $(document).ready(function() {

 var randomBg = 'url(img/bg' + Math.ceil(Math.random() * 3) + '.jpg)';
 var repeatBg = 'no-repeat center center';
 var sizeBg = 'cover';
 $('body').css('background', randomBg  + repeatBg);
});

Comment: вы не указали в примере, куда прописываете sizeBg - вероятно, этот параметр стоит не на своём месте в строке параметров для `background`. а потому и не срабатывает

Comment: Немного поправила, вроде работает, но все равно не совсем корректно $('body').css('background', randomBg  + repeatBg);
$('body').css('background-size', sizeBg);

Comment: Еще нюанс забыла упомянуть, у меня фон задается в css в классе HERO, но в js для класса свойства не срабатывают, поэтому задала через body. Может еще из-за этого непонятки?

Comment: *"но в js для класса свойства не срабатывают"* это как? Вот так не работает: `$('.hero').css('background-image', randomBg);` ?

Comment: О, ребята, вы лучшие) Всем спасибо за участие! П. С. Сорри, новичок в js.

Comment: Изменила класс на айди, работает!

Comment: Если вам дан исчерпывающий ответ, отметьте его как верный (галка напротив выбранного ответа).

Answer (score 1):

Ошибка, полагаю, в этой строке

```
$('body').css('background', randomBg + repeatBg);
```

Свойство `background` включает в себя и `background-image`, и `background-size`, которое, в случае, если не указано явно, меняется на дефолтное

Попробуйте

```
$('body').css('background-image', randomBg);
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$(window).on("load", function() {
    var randomBg = "url(img/bg" + Math.ceil(Math.random() * 3) + ".jpg)";
    $("body").css("background-image", randomBg)
});
```

Comment: интересно за что минус? кто-то подскажет?